# STL stack top() function reads same value even after pop().

Tags: c++, stl

I have a code for converting prefix string to infix. I have used stl stack.
Test input : */ab+-cde

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    stack<char*> s;
    char prefix[100],c;
    int l,i,flag[27]={0},pos;
    char *o1,*o2,*op,temp[10];
    cout<<"Prefix expression : ";
    cin>>prefix;
    l=strlen(prefix);
    op=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    o1=new char[10];
    o2=new char[10];
    for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(prefix[i]>=97 && prefix[i]<=122)
        {
            if(i!=l-1) cout<<s.top()<<endl;
            cout<<"Operand"<<endl;  
            temp[0]=prefix[i];
            temp[1]='\0';
            strcpy(op,temp);
            s.push(op);
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Operator"<<endl;
            cout<<"Top element : "<<s.top()<<endl;
            o1=s.top();
            strcpy(temp,o1);
            s.pop(); 
            cout<<"Top element : "<<s.top()<<endl;
            temp[strlen(temp)]=prefix[i];
            o2=s.top();
            strcat(temp,o2);
            s.pop();
            temp[strlen(temp)]='\0';
            //cout<<o1<<" "<<o2<<endl;
            strcpy(op,temp);
            s.push(op);
            cout<<op<<endl;
        }
    }
    o1=s.top();
    s.pop();
    cout<<"Evaluated expression is "<<o1<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now the o1 is supposed to store c when the first operand is encountered and o2 is supposed to store d.
But the output I get is as follows,

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chiha.png)

Can someone please help?

Comment: You really should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)s when working with strings.

Comment: Add the output to the question.

Comment: But this works fine when I use stack<char*> s and randomly insert s.push("hello") and so on.

Comment: Output added already.

Comment: @Sahitya If you want a container of strings, then use strings.  The type you should be using is `std::string`, not `char *`.  Change to `std::string`, and most, if not all of your issues will go away.  Also, why are you writing such `C` code in a C++ program?  `malloc`, seriously?

Comment: I haven't taken a close look - but you're using naked pointers to c-style strings - you malloc o1 and o2 only once outside the loop yet you're constantly assigning values to o1 and o2 inside the loop.  @PaulMcKenzie is on the right track: I'd just add that you should decide whether you're using C++ or C and read tutorials/books on the language you'd like to use and then code accordingly.

Comment: Every time you push `op` it's the same pointer. You change the string being pointed to, but the stack just has several instances of the same pointer.

Comment: Changed everything to std::string and works.

Comment: @Sahitya: External links go stale. You should add the text of your output to the question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I had initially used new, but since it showed me a segmentation fault I used malloc.

Comment: @Sahitya *but since it showed me a segmentation fault I used malloc.* -- No, that means there is a bug in your code.  Be lucky that `new[]` showed you that there is a problem.  All you would have done if you used malloc is to mask the problem, not fix it.  It's like sticking a piece of tape over your car's dashboard, just to hide the little light telling you something is wrong.

Comment: @Sahitya When you get a segmentation fault in your code, that allows you to track down the problem and fix it. Changing the code so it doesn't fault just wastes the opportunity to use the fault to point you right to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems I see in your code:

**Reusing `op` in the loop**

You have allocated memory for `op` before the start of the loop.

```
op=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
```

and then you are using the same memory in the `for` loop.

In the `if` block:

```
        strcpy(op,temp);
        s.push(op);
```

and in the `else` block.

```
        strcpy(op,temp);
        s.push(op);
```

You'll need to allocate memory for `op` each time.

**Using `strcat` with a string that is not null terminated**

In the `else` block, you have:

```
        temp[strlen(temp)]=prefix[i];
        o2=s.top();
        strcat(temp,o2);
```

The first of those lines replaces the null character of `temp` with `prefix[i]`. At that point, `temp` is not a null terminated string. The call to `strcat` in the third line above leads to undefined behavior.

You need to use something along the lines of:

```
        char temp2[2] = {0};
        temp2[0] = prefix[i];
        strcat(temp, temp2);
        o2=s.top();
        strcat(temp,o2);
```

**Mixing `malloc` and `new`**

Mixing `malloc` and `new` is not the cause of the memory issues you are seeing but it is better to stick to using `new` since you are in C++ land.

Here's a version of your program with the fixes:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   stack<char*> s;
   char prefix[100];
   int l,i;
   char *o1,*o2,*op,temp1[10],temp2[10];
   cout<<"Prefix expression : ";
   cin>>prefix;
   l=strlen(prefix);
   o1=new char[10];
   o2=new char[10];
   for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--)
   {
      if(prefix[i]>=97 && prefix[i]<=122)
      {
         if(i!=l-1) cout<<s.top()<<endl;
         cout<<"Operand"<<endl;  
         temp1[0]=prefix[i];
         temp1[1]='\0';
         op = new char[10];
         strcpy(op,temp1);
         s.push(op);
         cout<<"Symbol"<<endl;
         cout<<"Top element : "<<s.top()<<endl;
      }
      else
      {
         cout<<"Operator"<<endl;
         cout<<"Top element : "<<s.top()<<endl;
         o1=s.top();
         strcpy(temp1,o1);
         s.pop(); 
         cout<<"Top element : "<<s.top()<<endl;
         temp2[0]=prefix[i];
         temp2[1]='\0';

         strcat(temp1,temp2);
         o2=s.top();
         strcat(temp1,o2);
         s.pop();
         op = new char[10];
         strcpy(op,temp1);
         s.push(op);
         cout<<op<<endl;
      }
   }
   o1=s.top();
   s.pop();
   cout<<"Evaluated expression is "<<o1<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

**Update**

You can avoid the hassles of allocating and deallocating memory for your strings by using `std::string` instead of `char*`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void test(char prefix[])
{
   stack<std::string> s;
   int l,i;
   char temp[10] = {0};
   std::string op;

   l = std::strlen(prefix);
   for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--)
   {
      if(prefix[i]>=97 && prefix[i]<=122)
      {
         if(i!=l-1) cout<<s.top()<<endl;
         cout<<"Operand"<<endl;  
         temp[0]=prefix[i];
         s.push(temp);
         cout<<"Symbol"<<endl;
         cout<<"Top element : "<<s.top()<<endl;
      }
      else
      {
         cout<<"Operator"<<endl;
         cout<<"Top element : "<<s.top()<<endl;

         op = s.top();
         s.pop(); 

         cout<<"Top element : "<<s.top()<<endl;
         temp[0]=prefix[i];

         op += temp;

         op += s.top();
         s.pop();

         s.push(op);
         cout<<op<<endl;
      }
   }
   op=s.top();
   s.pop();
   cout<<"Evaluated expression is "<<op<<endl;
}

int main()
{
   char prefix[100];
   cout<<"Prefix expression : ";
   cin>>prefix;
   test(prefix);
   return 0;
}
```